# TeXShop Flashmode does not refresh

Tags: texshop

I'm using TeXShop (v3.26) and I've just downloaded [Flashmode](http://www.math.uni-heidelberg.de/studinfo/gerhardt/Flashmode/) (v7.1.1) which I put it into /Applications. Then I followed the instructions for the TeXShop/Preferences:

> uncheck the „Automatic Preview Update“ , set „Default Page Style“ to
>   „Multi-Page“ .
>
> Under Typesetting define the „Sync Method“ you would want to use. You
>   should select „SyncTeX“

I've checked, SyncTeX is working. But when I launch Flashmode (by clicking on the app or executing the script new_clone) it just **compile the .tex once** and not refresh it every 0.2s like it is expected !

I tested with the minimal test "*Flashmode-test.tex*" provided by the author in the folder :

```
~/Library/Application Support/Flashmode/Test-files
```

which looks like this :

```
%&pdflatex 
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{mathmacros}
\begin{document}
Notice the special command in the first line.

Start typing for otherwise Flashmode won't detect any modifications. 

\end{document}
```

So I start Flashmode, it compiles the .tex and display the pdf, but again once ! If I add some characters in the source it does not refresh the preview in real time. Why ?

These files have been created :

Flashmode-test.aux

```
\relax
\newlabel{tocindent-1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent0}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent1}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent2}{0pt}
\newlabel{tocindent3}{0pt}
```

Flashmode-test.flashmode

```
mardi 10 décembre 2013 15:30:16
```

Flashmode-test.flashmodeA

```
%&pdflatex
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{mathmacros}
\begin{document}
Notice the special command in the first line.

Start typing for otherwise Flashmode won't detect any modifications.

\end{document}
```

Flashmode-test.log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2013.11.26)  10 DEC 2013 15:30
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Flashmode-test.tex
(./Flashmode-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
\linespacing=\dimen102
\normalparindent=\dimen103
\normaltopskip=\skip41
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip42

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen104
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d
\pmbraise@=\dimen105
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count79
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count80
\leftroot@=\count81
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306.
\classnum@=\count82
\DOTSCASE@=\count83
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen106
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567.
\macc@depth=\count84
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count85
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count86
\dspbrk@lvl=\count87
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count88
\column@=\count89
\maxfields@=\count90
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen107
\alignsep@=\dimen108
\tagshift@=\dimen109
\tagwidth@=\dimen110
\totwidth@=\dimen111
\lineht@=\dimen112
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip43
\multlinetaggap=\skip44
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2665.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 388.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert233
\abstractbox=\box28
\listisep=\skip45
\c@part=\count91
\c@section=\count92
\c@subsection=\count93
\c@subsubsection=\count94
\c@paragraph=\count95
\c@subparagraph=\count96
\c@figure=\count97
\c@table=\count98
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\captionindent=\dimen113
\thm@style=\toks19
\thm@bodyfont=\toks20
\thm@headfont=\toks21
\thm@notefont=\toks22
\thm@headpunct=\toks23
\thm@preskip=\skip48
\thm@postskip=\skip49
\thm@headsep=\skip50
\dth@everypar=\toks24
)
No file Flashmode-test.aux.
\openout1 = `Flashmode-test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 4.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 4.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./Flashmode-test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1361 strings out of 493315
 15213 string characters out of 6137903
 66713 words of memory out of 5000000
 4700 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7385 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1118 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,4n,28p,267b,185s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/
amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on Flashmode-test.pdf (1 page, 22566 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Flashmode-test.pdf

Flashmode-test.position

Flashmode-test.synctex.gz

What is strange is that I can't find any process named Flashmode with the command line "ps -A" after executing it. I suppose that if Flashmode should refresh in real time the preview it has to appear in the current process list, hasn't it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Flashmode will immediately quit when the language chosen in the OS is different from English. Hence, I added a version 7.1.8 special to the download that will work properly in this case. However, F. will then discard checking if there are different copies of Flashmode controlling the same document.